# How to migrate/convert current OOP PHP project to CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, frameworks, migrate

I already have a working OOP website. Most of the php is separated from the html. I was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to apply that site into the CI Framework. The website uses jquery, html, css, php, javascript. It also consists of a lot of libraries and classes that I bought from code canyon. For example, a geolocation library, phpthumb (image thumbnails), like and dislike system. How does one go about importing these libraries into CI?

Comment: Reading about [creating Libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) and [Application Packages](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html) might be a good place to start.

Comment: There is no "Do X" solution here. You have to do it manually. For anything that isnt compatible with CI you need to write an Adapter.

Comment: Yes. I know that. I'm simply asking for tips that would help me speed up the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't a 'step by step' process to give you.

You have to ultimately do the following:

1. Outline each and every component to migrate into CI
2. Test each component under CI (many libraries can be loaded just fine under CI, and play nice with the rest of your code, but do need to be tested). Read here about [creating your own (custom) libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) and using them under CI.
3. Create the required **controllers**
4. Create the required **models**
5. Create & copy over your HTML and structure them in **views**
6. Test.. test.. and test some more

Its not a simple process, but breaking it down lets you see what you have before you.